# What is the best way to do the long background task in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, background-task

I'm developing Windows Metro App and in my App I need to download some information(about 60Mb, every time) from server in background. Download should occur regularly, for example every 8 hours. So I tried to use Background Task, but there are some CPU and network quotas(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977051.aspx), and I can't do this. Could somebody help me with advice in this problem?

Comment: Does your app always need to download that much? What is the pupose of the donwload?

Comment: You should think more about your application. Not much sense to download 60 Mb from a tablet every few hours.

Comment: I want to make an app which can update lock screen images. User only choose time period and app will update images, even if user doesn't run app all week, for example. That's why I need to download so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to do the entire transfer in the background task itself, have the background task start a background *transfer*, which runs independent of the task and independent of the app as well. See the topic, Transferring Data in the Background, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx. You can run the background task periodically according to the schedule you need, and it will easily stay under CPU and networking quotas because the background transfer doesn't count against that.